# Getting activity field from devops rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

We have some fields in DevOps, and I would like to get the field called activivty:
[image]

I use following call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=5.1&$expand=Fields
```

I get most of the info on the work item, but not the activity value. Any pointers on how to get this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Activity  field value of the work item, you can check the filed: `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity` in the Rest API response.

Since you are using the Rest API: [Work Items - Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-items-batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP), you can refer to the following sample:

Rest API:

```
Post https://dev.azure.com/orgname/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "ids": [
    workitemids
  ],
  
  "fields": [
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity"
   
  ]

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Your totally right. The problem was I was testing on some old work items that did not have this field. Thanks.